# Interop: when deploying a VB6 + .NET component, is the .TLB needed?

Tags: .net, vb6, interop

When deploying a software package containing a VB6 executable and a .NET component, is the .TLB file needed?

If not, would it be sufficient to include the .DLL and have it regasm-ed during installation?

Answer (score 6):

If you were to include the .tlb file in the install, you would need a way to register that file for COM.

Instead, you can exclude the .tlb file and just regasm the dll; the .tlb will be created and registered on the user's system.

Comment: This is a surprise, but according to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx, it sure sounds like you don't need to distribute the TLB for the .net assembly. I always thought you did. I'll have to go back and try that later.

Answer (score 0):

You will need both the .DLL and .TLB file.  Registering during installation is what I think you should do if you don't put it in the GAC.  Run RegAsm with the `/codebase` command line switch.

Also make sure set the .NET assembly property `COMVisible = true`.